# Quantum Jordan Algebras(Still wondering!)

Tags: abstract-algebra, reference-request

I have attempted to google for this, but the searching is marred by the close relationship of Jordan Algebras and Quantum Mechanics. I have been passively thinking of this question for ages, tonight I finally post it. :)

<strike>My question is fairly simple. Similar to the universal enveloping algebra for Lie algebras, we should be able to form a universal enveloping algebra for Jordan algebras. So question one:</strike>

> Can we indeed construct this "Universal enveloping algebra"?(Thanks Matt)

We can form a Universal enveloping algebra for Jordan algebras. So;

> Are there some sort of Serre relations for Jordan algebras?

and then as we do for Lie algebras,

> Can we find "quantum Jordan 'Serre' relations" for quantum Jordan algebras?

or just;

> Can we deform the Jordan Universal Enveloping algebra in a similar way that we deform Lie Enveloping algebras to their quantized versions?

I would be happy with an explanation or a reference.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

Yes, there is a notion of universal enveloping algebra for Jordan algbera; it is left adjoint
to the functor that associates a Jordan algebra to an associative algebra.

However, there is no analogue of the Poincare--Birkhoff--Witt theorem for Jordan algebras,
and so the map from the Jordan algebra to its universal enveloping algebra need not be injective.  (I forget where I learned this, but it should be discussed in most texts that discuss Jordan algebras; indeed, there is an adjective --- which I also forget --- used to separate those Jordan algebras that do embed into their enveloping algebra from those that
don't.)

As for deformation quantization, I don't know.